# The options displayed in my dropdown list is not saved to my database using JSP

Tags: jsp

I want to save values shown on a dropdown list to the database. The list is retrieved from another database. When I try saving it, the id column of the table will be saved instead of the values shown on the dropdown list.

I have two databases (cmsdb) and (testDB). 
testDB has a table (programme of study) with two columns (pos_id) and (pos_name). cmsdb has a table(kasuStudent).

The code fragment below loads the values from the "programme of study" table to a dropdown list successfully.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Programme*</td>
            <td><p>
            <select name='Programme' onchange="showDepartment(this.value)">  
                <option value="none">--Select Programme--</option>  
                <%
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "");
                    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from programmeofstudy");
                    while (rs.next()) {

                %>
                <option value=<%=rs.getString(1)%>><%=rs.getString(2)%></option>  
                <%
                    }
                %>
            </select>                                        
        <p></td>
</tr>
```

The problem as mentioned earlier is, whenever I attempt to save the values. The pos_id will be saved to kasuStudentDB instead of pos_name been saved.

How do I make pos_name to saved please.

This is the code fragment for the inserting to database incase you need to see it.

```
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%

String programmeOfStudy = request.getParameter("Programme");

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = 
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cmsdb",
        "root", "");
Statement st = con.createStatement();
int i = st.executeUpdate("insert into kasustudent(CourseOfStudy) values ('" + programmeOfStudy + "')");
if (i > 0) {
  %>

<script language='javascript'>
    window.alert('Account Successfully Created!! \n Login to access your Dashboard!');
    window.location='StudentLogin.jsp';
</script>
<%     

} else {
 %>

<script language='javascript'>
    window.alert('Account Not Created Try again!');
    window.location='StudentCreateAccount.jsp';
</script>
```

Thank you for your anticipated response.

Answer (score 0):

instead:

```
<option value=<%=rs.getString(1)%>><%=rs.getString(2)%></option>
```

do it:

```
<option value=<%=rs.getString(2)%>><%=rs.getString(2)%></option>
```

So... write java code in jsp is bad. Try to move your java code to a servlet and read about EL.

> https://beginnersbook.com/2013/11/jsp-expression-language-el/
>
> https://www.baeldung.com/intro-to-servlets

Comment: Thank you for the response and suggestion. I will move the java code to a servlet.